# Generate permutations of a subset of a List<List<KeyPairValue<string, string>>> in C#

Tags: c#, list, permutation

Please take a look at the following example code:

```
List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> list = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

list.Add(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
list[0].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 1", "Value A"));
list[0].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 1", "Value B"));

list.Add(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
list[1].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 2", "Value C"));
list[1].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 2", "Value D"));

list.Add(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
list[2].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 3", "Value E"));
```

It can also be represented as such:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value A"] | ["Category 1", "Value B"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 2", "Value C"] | ["Category 2", "Value D"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 3", "Value E"] |                           |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

I need these values rearranged in a manner where each column will hold one unique category and I must *copy and swap* values around so that all possible permutation of values given the category restriction is achieved. In other words...

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value A"] | ["Category 2", "Value C"] | ["Category 3", "Value E"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value B"] | ["Category 2", "Value D"] | ["Category 3", "Value E"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value B"] | ["Category 2", "Value C"] | ["Category 3", "Value E"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value A"] | ["Category 2", "Value D"] | ["Category 3", "Value E"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Notice that I have swapped the third and fourth values in the first column in order to achieve unique rows. Please disregard which column to use when considering my problem, it doesn't matter which values are swapped as long as I end up with unique rows in this particular column/category order. Also, like I previously said, this is only an example, I need something that will work regardless the amount of elements.

Here is what I have so far (the variable list here is the same as above):

```
int elementAmount = list.Count;
int combinationAmount = list.Select(x => x.Count).Aggregate(1, (x, y) => x * y); //Multiply sublists element count

List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> sortedList = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(combinationAmount);

for (int i = 0; i < combinationAmount; i++)
sortedList.Add(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(elementAmount));

for (int j = 0; j < elementAmount; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < combinationAmount; i++)
        sortedList[i].Add(list[j].Count > i ? list[j][i] : sortedList[i - list[j].Count][j]);
}
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value A"] | ["Category 2", "Value C"] | ["Category 3", "Value E"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value B"] | ["Category 2", "Value D"] | ["Category 3", "Value E"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value A"] | ["Category 2", "Value C"] | ["Category 3", "Value E"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| ["Category 1", "Value B"] | ["Category 2", "Value D"] | ["Category 3", "Value E"] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

I apologise if I came up with a misleading title, it's a bit hard to summarise the whole problem in a single line. Please edit it to your heart's content.

***EDIT***: I'm only missing the swap.

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) that might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the answer to the question.  Please note that after that I will post something that isn't muddled by the data structure that just shows permutation through recursion.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> list = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

        list.Add(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
        list[0].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 1", "Value A"));
        list[0].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 1", "Value B"));

        list.Add(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
        list[1].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 2", "Value C"));
        list[1].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 2", "Value D"));

        list.Add(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
        list[2].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Category 3", "Value E"));

        List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> sortedList = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

        permutation(list, 0, new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
    }


    private void permutation( List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> options, int srcPos, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> result)
    {
        if (result.Count == options.Count)
            WriteOne(result);
        else
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> opt in options[srcPos])
            {
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> theClone = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(result); 
                theClone.Add(opt); 
                permutation(options, srcPos + 1, theClone);
            }
        }
    }

    private void WriteOne(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> OneResult)
    {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(80);
        StringBuilder line2 = new StringBuilder(80);
        line.Append("|"); line2.Append("+");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in OneResult)
        {
            line.Append(" [");       line2.Append("--");
            line.Append(item.Key);   line2.Append(new string('-', item.Key.Length));
            line.Append(", ");       line2.Append("--");
            line.Append(item.Value); line2.Append(new string('-', item.Value.Length));
            line.Append("] |");     line2.Append("--+");
        }
        line.AppendLine(); line2.AppendLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(line2.ToString());
    }
```

Now the simpler thing which was what spawned the one above.  It's the same exact algorithm but the generic List notation doesn't muddy it up.

```
    private void Test()
    {
        permutation(new string[] { "AB", "CD", "E" }, 0, "");
    }


    private void permutation(string[] options, int srcPos, string result)
    {
        if (result.Length == options.Length)
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        else
        {
            foreach (char opt in options[srcPos])
            {
                permutation(options, srcPos + 1, result + opt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll be waiting

Comment: "all these lists are hurtin my brain" LOL I know how it feels, I've been on them for the past 3 hours or so. I'm trying some different things here as well, but I've reached the point where I have just staggered.

Comment: I'm leaving for the day but if you manage to come up with something, I'll be sure to check it on Monday. Cheers!

Comment: If you vote up my solution then I might get to comment some day!

Comment: You are THE KING man! I'll have to fiddle with it a bit so that it fits my real-case scenario, but that's the way it should be! Thank you so much, I'd upvote you twice if I could!

Comment: Alright, it worked in the real deal! I can't thank you enough!